# Is there any pandas function to do a paired mapping?

Tags: python, pandas, mapping

I have two tables. The first table contains actual data and some columns, which needs to be replaced respectively, let's call them A and B. There is another table that holds rules for mapping and looks as follows:

| А | B | A_target | B_target |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XX | YY | XX | YY1 |
| XX | ZZ | XX1 | ZZ1 |

So, I need to do a respective mapping based on that table, e. g. if I have value XX and YY in columns A and B they become XX and YY1.

XX and ZZ -> XX1 and ZZ1

How can I implement it using pandas?

Comment: `df.merge(table, on=['A', 'B'], how='left')`?

Answer (score 0):

There are ways you could do this directly, but I believe a simpler solution would achieve the same result and help you avoid mistakes. Since `A_target` and `B_target` seem to be computed independently (both depend only on `A` and `B`), you could apply 2 separate operations on columns `A` and `B` to get `A_target` and `B_target` separately.

After that, you can replace the initial columns if needed.

##### Solution 1 (for simple operations)

If `A_target` and `B_target` are the result of some simple math operation, you could compute them using vectorized operations:

```
df['A_target'] = df['A'] + df['B']
df['B_target'] = df['A'] * df['B']
```

The operations above are just an example.

##### Solution 2 (for more complex operations)

If `A_target` and `B_target` are the result of some complex operations, then you could use the `apply` function.

```
def compute_A_target(df_row):
    # some computation based on A and B
    A_target = df_row['A'] + df_row['B']
    return A_target

def compute_B_target(df_row):
    # some computation based on A and B
    B_target = df_row['A'] * df_row['B']
    return B_target

df['A_target'] = df.apply(compute_A_target, axis=1) 
df['B_target'] = df.apply(compute_B_target, axis=1)
```

(`axis=1` is required so the function is applied on each row)

In the end, you could replace columns `A` and `B` with `A_target` and `B_target` by removing `A` and `B` and renaming `A_target` and `B_target`:

```
df.drop(columns=['A', 'B'], inplace=True)
df.rename(columns={'A_target':'A', 'B_target':'B'}, inplace=True)
```